# Как cделать отображение тегов <style="H1"> и <style="Link">?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

Мне нужно сделать `markdown` для сайта, но со специфическим синтаксисом юнита:

```
<b>жирненький текстик</b>
<i>италик</i>
<u>подчеркнутый</u>
<s>зачеркнутый</s>

перенос<br>строки

<style="H1">заголовочек 1</style>
<style="H2">заголовочек 2</style>

<a href="https://www.unity.com"><style="Link">ссылочка </a></style>
```

Всё бы нормально, `react-markdown` может отображать обычные теги, но `<style="H1">` и `<style="Link">` - отказывается.

Единственное что приходит в голову - регуляркой менять `style` на `h1` и так отдавать `react-markdown`'у, но наступает проблема со вложенностью тегов между ссылками и заголовками. Уже полдня пытаюсь функцию для этого написать, но надеюсь что должно быть более простое решение. Допустим какое-то указание `react-markdown` того как он должен специфические теги воспринимать.

Comment: Для более полного понимания обратитесь к сводной таблице https://markdown69.com/ Там представлены наиболее необходимые способы форматирования